# iphone objectiveC alloc/release question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory

I am new to ObjectiveC language.
I am having trouble understanding memory management syntax.
My code is below:

```
NSDate* someDate;
someDate=[[NSDate alloc] init];
loop
{ 
   someDate=[[NSDate alloc] init];
}
```

will I have a memory leak here ? or the NSDate object returned is [autorelease]?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

As @DavidKanarek says, you will have leaks.

There are a number of ways to fix these leaks :

```
NSDate* someDate;
someDate=[NSDate date];
loop
{ 
   someDate=[NSDate date];
}
```

or

```
NSDate* someDate=nil;
someDate=[[NSDate alloc] init];
loop
{ 
   [someDate release];
   someDate=[[NSDate alloc] init];
}

[someDate release];
```

The first one is easier code to read but the second one keeps your memory usage down as low as possible. If your loop is not too big, use the first. If you're going through the loop thousands of times, I'd use the second.

Sam

Comment: I would even argue to use option one when having thousands of loops. Let the system handle when to release those NSDate objects as it balances out performance under the covers. There may be a loop performance disadvantage in looping thousands of times and releasing at each stage. Interested in hearing your thoughts.

Answer (score 4):

You will have many memory leaks. Objects are initially retained (not autoreleased) if they are returned by methods that have new, alloc or copy in the name. `[NSDate date]` would be autoreleased. If you post more substantive code I can give you some help in accomplishing your goal cleanly.

Also have a look at [Apple's Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).

Comment: So it has nothing to do with alloc?

Comment: I think he means methods that have alloc, new or copy in the name.

Comment: David.. thanks...here are more details.
The main point of my code is to update the "someDate" variable with the "current date" in the loop.

Comment: @DavidKanarek - The alloc causes the retain count to be set to 1, not the init.

Comment: @luliu I would use `someDate=[NSDate date]` and profile your application to make sure the memory usage is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

This object-ownership scheme is implemented through a reference-counting system that internally tracks how many owners each object has. When you claim ownership of an object, you increase it’s reference count, and when you’re done with the object, you decrease its reference count. While its reference count is greater than zero, an object is guaranteed to exist, but as soon as the count reaches zero, the operating system is allowed to destroy it.

http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/memory-management

But in latest xcode it provide ARC (Automatic reference counting).
So It will manage reference count automatically .when class is deallocate it release memory for all object it content within .

Answer (score 0):

You will have lots memory leaks.

`someDate` is a poninter variable and is assigned a block of memory that you allocate, in this case is `[[NSDate alloc] init]`.

However, in the loop you assign your pointer variable to another memory bolck (`someDate=[NSDate date]`)

The memory leak occurs as those memory blocks which have already allocated are unreleased.